# Problemas com a ScroolView no Android Studio

Tags: java, android-layout

Bom dia, sou novo em programação Android e estou tentando criar um programa que baseado numa matéria que o usuário escolher, abrirá uma determinada tela, tudo que fui fazendo foi baseado em pesquisa em sites, vídeos e etc; porém ao compilar o programa e executá-lo, ele trava quando clico no botão para ir para o menu (esse da print), e simplesmente fecha. Achei que o erro poderia ser na barra de pesquisa, porém usei a mesma em outras duas telas e funcionou, então creio que o problema seja na Scrool View. A ideia seria ela girar em vertical para exibir as outras matérias e a barra de pesquisa permanecer estática acima. 
Agradeço a quem puder ajudar :)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

código da activity:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/blue" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="@string/textView"
        android:labelFor="@id/toolbar2"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/my_account"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/account"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="conta"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/search_user"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/my_account"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/magnify"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="obras"/>


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">


        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">



                  <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                         <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/imageButtonArte"
                                android:layout_width="160dp"
                                android:layout_height="160dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:background="@color/transparente"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icone_arte"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:onClick="obras"/>



                        <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/imageButtonBiologia"
                                android:layout_width="160dp"
                                android:layout_height="160dp"
                                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                                android:background="@color/transparente"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icone_biologia"
                                android:onClick="obras"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                 <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/imageButtonFilosofia"
                                android:layout_width="160dp"
                                android:layout_height="160dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                android:background="@color/transparente"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:onClick="obras"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icone_filosofia"/>

                        <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/imageButtonFisica"
                                android:layout_width="160dp"
                                android:layout_height="160dp"
                                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:background="@color/transparente"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:onClick="obras"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icone_fisica" />

                </LinearLayout>

                 <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/imageButtonGeografia"
                                android:layout_width="160dp"
                                android:layout_height="160dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:background="@color/transparente"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                android:visibility="visible"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:onClick="obras"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icone_geografia" />

                        <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/imageButtonHistoria"
                                android:layout_width="160dp"
                                android:layout_height="160dp"
                                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                                android:background="@color/transparente"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:onClick="obras"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icone_historia" />

                 </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/imageButtonMatematica"
                                android:layout_width="160dp"
                                android:layout_height="160dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:background="@color/transparente"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:onClick="obras"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icone_matematica" />

                        <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/imageButtonPortugues"
                                android:layout_width="160dp"
                                android:layout_height="160dp"
                                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                                android:background="@color/transparente"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icone_portugues"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:onClick="obras"/>
                 </LinearLayout>


                      <LinearLayout
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="match_parent"
                         android:orientation="horizontal">

                              <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/imageButtonQuimica"
                                android:layout_width="160dp"
                                android:layout_height="160dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:background="@color/transparente"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:onClick="obras"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icone_quimica" />

                              <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/imageButtonSociologia"
                                android:layout_width="160dp"
                                android:layout_height="160dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                                android:background="@color/transparente"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:onClick="obras"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icone_sociologia" />

                      </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o erro esteja nos parâmetros que você colocou nos `layout_width` e `layout_height`, que estão todos `match_parent`... por exemplo, o pirmeiro `LinearLayout` está como `match_parent` nos 2, tenta por um `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` e também nos LinearLayout's que sejam horizontais, porque eles estão tentando ocupar a tela inteira...